# opening bootstrap modal makes element shift

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I wonder if someone can give me a hand.
I am building a website where a form is in bootstrap modal and triggered from a fixed position element.
The problem is when I modal is opened, "trigger" shifts to side.
I could be able to prevent this by placing 
`body{
    overflow: scroll !important;
    }`
But I am afraid it will give me problems somewhere else
This is link to dev : 
     `http://dogether.www023.in.rs/`

Modal is opened by clicking a bubble on right side of a screen (fixed position)

Like I said, it works the way I want just for some reason trigger element is moving on modal open
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The element is moving because your are removing the body scroll, this in turn increases the width of the page. So when width increases your bubble is moving.

Comment: When you place fixed element from right side i.e right = 30px or so, it will move. The work around would be to place it according to left i.e left = 500px or so.

Comment: When i removed right property on class=".popup_trigger_holder" the bubble is not moving.

Comment: Thank you all!Yes, removing right property fixes it. Guess I will need something else for mobile devices anyways.